# Como Validar Una Imagen de Login en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, login

Estoy intentando hacer un login que se valide con 4 campos que son:
-login
-password
-correo
-Firma(Imagen)

Hasta ahora todo funciona bien excepto la parte que debe comparar la variable que contiene la imagen

```
<?php 

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "profesor", "profesor1", "practica");

$usuario = $_POST["login"];
$contraseña = $_POST["password"];
$correo = $_POST["email"];

$firmaDigital = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["firma"]["tmp_name"]));

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario='$usuario'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);

if($fila[0]==$usuario){
    if($fila[1]==$contraseña){
        if($fila[2]==$correo){

            //ESTA ES LA PARTE DONDE SE COMPARA LA IMAGEN

            if($fila[3]==$firmaDigital){
                echo "Bienvenido " . $usuario;

            }else{
                echo "No estas logeado 3";
            }

            //---------------------------------------------

            header("location: PerfilDocente.html");

        }else{
            echo "No estas logeado 2";
        }

    }else{
        echo "No estas logeado 1";
    }

}else{
    echo "No estas logeado 0";
}
```

?>

El punto es que no se como comparar esta variable con la imagen para poder logearme puesto que de inmediato me pasa al mensaje "No estas logeado 3",
les agradeceria que me ayudaran porfavor.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura de la tabla: login?

Comment: la tabla login se compone de usuario, contraseña, correo y firma digital que es de tipo BLOB

Comment: Entonces si es de tipo BLOB es una imagen codificada. Por eso el mensaje "No estas logeado 3", porque estás comparando una imagen codificada con otra que no lo está.

Comment: Si, supongo que ese es mi problema en un principio, ese dato BLOB lo tengo en la base de datos y lo traigo para compararlo con una variable que captura una imagen asi $firmaDigital = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["firma"]["tmp_name"])); quiero saber de que forma puedo compararlos

Comment: Se me complica probar tu código, pero ¿probaste $firmaDigital = file_get_contents($_FILES["firma"]["tmp_name"]); quitando el addslashes ?